# Rails ActionMailer won't send from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I've read all the other SO answers, but I still can't fix this.

Given my `RewardMailer` has the following email defined:

```
# A test email to check up on the configurations
def test_mail
  @recipients = 'aminshahgilani@gmail.com'
  @from = 'postmaster@sandboxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mailgun.org'
  @subject = 'test from the Rails Console'
  @body = 'This is a test email'
end
```

And that my `config/environments/development.rb` file contains:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.mailgun.org',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'sandboxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mailgun.org',
  user_name: 'postmaster@sandboxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mailgun.org',
  password:             'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  authentication:       :plain
}
```

And when I check from the Rails console, I confirm the configuration with:

```
Rails.application.config.action_mailer
 => {:perform_deliveries=>true, :raise_delivery_errors=>true, :delivery_method=>:smtp, :smtp_settings=>{:address=>"smtp.mailgun.org", :port=>587, :domain=>"sandbox0574dfb215d14874ac51fb9f9052131b.mailgun.org", :user_name=>"postmaster@sandboxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mailgun.org", :password=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", :authentication=>:plain}, :assets_dir=>"/home/gilani/Sandbox/mailman/public", :javascripts_dir=>"/home/gilani/Sandbox/mailman/public/javascripts", :stylesheets_dir=>"/home/gilani/Sandbox/mailman/public/stylesheets", :preview_path=>"/home/gilani/Sandbox/mailman/test/mailers/previews", :asset_host=>nil, :relative_url_root=>nil}
```

**Why does the following not deliver my email? Or show any error for it at all**

```
RewardMailer.test_mail().deliver_now

RewardMailer#test_mail: processed outbound mail in 0.1ms
 => nil
```

I checked with my Mailgun logs as well, nothing. The logs are empty!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not calling `mail` method in your test_mail.